# What's the best way to deal with multiple monitors?

Tags: visual-c++, multiple-monitors

I want to create a game that will take advantage of multiple monitors. For example, if the user has 3 monitors side by side I want the program to spread the image across all 3 monitors.

How am I supposed to do this? Can I just make one really big window, or do I have to do 3 separate windows? And if I have to do separate windows, how do I know the orientation of the monitors?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using DirectX or OpenGL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows provides a "virtual desktop", so you can usually just create Windows on the desktop, and let the OS deal with mapping those to physical monitors. When/if you need to know which parts of the virtual desktop will show up on which monitors, you can use [`EnumDisplayMonitors`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162610%28VS.85%29.aspx) (among several possibilities) to do so.

Comment: I don't quite understand. So for example if I wanted to spread the window across 2 monitors, both with 1024x768, should I create a big window that's 2048x768 or two separate 1024x768 windows?

Comment: If you want to create one window that covers both monitors, you'd do the 2048x768 version. My advice, however, would be to let the user arrange his windows as he sees fit, and save the arrangement between sessions. When you start a session, verify that the virtual desktop hasn't changed (it's annoying when windows are created off-screen).

Answer (score 2):

Make your game scalable to any size, and lat their video drivers scale it across the monitors their own way.

Comment: The OS does abstract `some` things.